# Linked SQL Server e FireBird: Erro 'Must declare the scalar variable'

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

Fiz um *linked* do meu `SQLSERVER` com o `FIREBIRD`. Mas na hora que passo uma variável dentro da consulta para retornar a quantidade de registro recebo o erro:

> Mensagem 137, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 1 Must declare the scalar
>   variable "@QtdReg".

***Script***:

```
DECLARE @LINKED VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SQL_LINKED VARCHAR(7000)
DECLARE @OPENQRY VARCHAR(7000)
DECLARE @QtdReg VARCHAR(700)
declare @codpro varchar(10)

SET @codpro = '1000'
SET @LINKED = 'Mylinked'

SET @SQL_LINKED = 'SELECT count(1) as total FROM produto i WHERE CAST(I.codigoref AS VARCHAR(10)) = '''''+@CodPro+''''' and i.caixa=201 '

SET @OPENQRY = ' SELECT  @QtdReg  =  ItemFT.total FROM  Openquery('+@LINKED+', '''+@SQL_LINKED+''') ItemFT'

EXECUTE (@OPENQRY)
SELECT @QTDREG
```

Tentei utilizar `SP_executesql` também ocorre o erro. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Creio que o problema aí é que no escopo de execução do `EXECUTE(@OPENQRY)` a variável `@QtdReg` não está declarada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer retornar o valor em uma variável, substitua o `EXECUTE` pela `sp_executesql`:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @OPENQRY,
                      N'@QtdReg VARCHAR(7000) OUTPUT',
                      @QtdReg = @QtdReg OUTPUT;
```

---

> [**`sp_executesql`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188001(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Executa uma instrução ou lote Transact-SQL que pode ser reutilizado muitas vezes ou que foi criado dinamicamente. A instrução ou lote do Transact-SQL pode conter parâmetros inseridos.

---

> [**Usando `sp_executesql`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> Para executar uma cadeia de caracteres, recomendamos que você use o procedimento armazenado `sp_executesql` em vez da instrução `EXECUTE`. Como esse procedimento armazenado dá suporte à substituição de parâmetro, o `sp_executesql` é mais versátil que `EXECUTE`; e como o `sp_executesql` gera planos de execução mais prováveis de serem reusados pelo `SQL Server`, o `sp_executesql` é mais eficiente que `EXECUTE`.